# DrawableのshapeでWidthを画面サイズに設定したい

Tags: android, xml

AndroidのDrawableリソースのshape(四角形)のWidth要素をXMLで画面サイズいっぱいに設定することはできますか｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match_parent等は実際にレイアウトに配置されないと使えないのでshapeには指定できないのでは。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111393/can-a-drawable-shape-have-its-size-set-to-fill-parent